# Core Data unresolved error on save

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm getting an error when saving my core data context, here is the log:

```
Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134030.)" UserInfo=0x1937a0 {NSAffectedStoresErrorKey=(
    "<NSSQLCore: 0x156410>"
), NSUnderlyingError=0x181a60 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)", NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/appid/Documents/appname.sqlite}, {
    NSAffectedStoresErrorKey =     (
        "<NSSQLCore: 0x156410>"
    );
    NSFilePath = "/var/mobile/Applications/appid/Documents/appname.sqlite";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)\" UserInfo=0x181a30 {NSUnderlyingError=0x108ab0 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"}";
}
```

I receive this error after removing and deleting an object:

```
[productList removeMProductObject:product];
[[delegate managedObjectContext] deleteObject:product];
[delegate saveContext];
```

I also noted that i also receive the error for the following scenarios(debugging):

```
1.
    [productList removeMProductObject:product];
    [delegate saveContext];

2.
    [[delegate managedObjectContext] deleteObject:product];
    [delegate saveContext];

3.
    [[delegate managedObjectContext] deleteObject:product];
    [productList removeMProductObject:product];
    [delegate saveContext];

4.
    [[delegate managedObjectContext] deleteObject:product];
    [delegate saveContext];//error
    [productList removeMProductObject:product];
    [delegate saveContext];

5.
    [productList removeMProductObject:product];
    [delegate saveContext];//error
    [[delegate managedObjectContext] deleteObject:product];
    [delegate saveContext];
```

At times, i may pass around either the `productList` or a `product` object (both of type `NSManagedObject`) to other controllers, always using `assign` in the property and never `retain`. `productList` is an object which may contain many `product` objects.

I **am** able to create new objects(`NSManagedObject`), but when it comes to deleting them i get the error mentioned above.  When running the application in the simulator i keep a close eye on the sqlite file.  after attempting to delete an object(code above), i notice the .sqlite file is removed.

I have created a few Core Data iphone applications with no problem but i seem to be having an issue here.  i don't believe i am doing anything out of the ordinary but perhaps i am missing a small detail, but i don't know what!

**Why is my .sqlite file being deleted and resulting in this error message on save?**

**How can i find a more useful error message so i can determine the cause of this error?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found the problem, but i'm not sure why it fixes it:

Before i would delete/remove the object i would delete the image associated with it(stored in the document's directory).

The image by default has no value(nil), but i would attempt to delete it anyway:

```
    NSError *deleteError = nil;
      [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[DOCUMENTS_DIRECTORY stringByAppendingPathComponent:product.mPictureName] error:&deleteError];
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
      if(deleteError) {
        NSLog(@"Error deleting image: %@", [deleteError description]);
      }
      else {
        NSLog(@"Image %@ deleted.", product.mPictureName);
      }
#endif
```

if i instead do a nil check before attempting to remove the image like this, i get no error when i delete the managed object itself:

```
    NSString *imageName = product.mPictureName;
    if(imageName) {
      NSError *deleteError = nil;
      [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[DOCUMENTS_DIRECTORY stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName] error:&deleteError];
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
      if(deleteError) {
        NSLog(@"Error deleting image: %@", [deleteError description]);
      }
      else {
        NSLog(@"Image %@ deleted.", imageName);
      }
#endif
    }
    ...
    //delete NSManagedObject and save
```

i guess attempting to access the product's picture when it is nil makes it all invalid.

Comment: Thank you SO VERY MUCH. I've had exactly the same problem and the solution was to nil check the images first.

Comment: Man, awesome. I spent forever on this.

Comment: This: *"after attempting to delete an object(code above), i notice the .sqlite file is removed."* sounds like you were actually deleting the entire Documents directory if `imageName` was nil, since `removeItemAtPath:` also removes directories recursively and appending nil to the documents path effectively does nothing.

Comment: this happens because you are throwing an exception in removeItemAtPath. but since you are inside a block owned by your document save operation it crashes the app.

Comment: awesome.. it saved my day .. thnx :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that's worth reporting for any poor shmo that gets caught up in this issue.  In my case I had a table view controller that handled row deletions by deleting the corresponding data from the data model.  When I used the remove##ObjectName##Object method (stubbed out by the auto-generated NSManagedObject subclass), I would get an error similar to the one you reported.

When I instead used NSManagedObjectContext: deleteObject I didn't have a problem saving the context.  But, I observed an exception being thrown with no indication of reason from the console.

It turns out the tableView method canEditRowAtIndexPath: was being called for the row corresponding to the newly deleted object.  It was clear my row count needed to be updated prior to the OS calling this method.  But, I don't care.  I simply check to see whether the size of my array of managed objects can be indexed by the indexPath row.

```
   if([managedObjSet.objects count] > indexPath.row) {
        ManagedObject* obj = [managedObjectArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return ([obj.anotherManagedObjSet count] ==0);
    }
```